# Explicit calculation of map of singular homology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have a question about calculating an explicit mapping of singular homology. Take for example the isomorphism $H_2(U,U-\{x\})\cong H_2(S^2,S^2-\{x\})$ induced by excision.  We can write $S^2$ as two $2$-simplices $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ giving each hemisphere so that $H_2(S^2,S^2-\{x\})$ is generated by $\Delta_1-\Delta_2$.

Now, I know that the isomorphism above is induced by the inclusion map. But what precisely is this map? Say $U\ni x$ is in the hemisphere given by $\Delta_1$. It seems intuitive to me, at least, that the a generator for $H_2(U,U-\{x\})$ is some simplex $\sigma\colon\Delta^2\rightarrow U$ such that $\sigma$ includes $x$ and that the orientation "agrees" with that of $\Delta_1$. To show that this is the case, I'd have to show that the $\sigma$ and $\Delta_1$, in $H_2(S^2,S^2-\{x\})$, are off by a relative boundary. I'm not exactly sure how to prove this in a way that easily generalizes to higher dimensions.

For context, all of this arose when thinking about calculating local degree.

Comment: You have to say what is $U$. And preferably also say what is $S^2$ - although one can guess that it means the two dimensional sphere.

Comment: By $S^2$ I mean the two-dimensional sphere. $U$ is some open neighborhood of $x$, say contained in $\Delta_1$.

Comment: Yes, and also what the symbol "2" means!
It's totally clear what is meant by $U$ and $S^2$.

Comment: The $2$-cell thing I replaced with $2$-simplex; $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are two maps from a triangle into $S^2$, to, say, the upper and lower hemisphere respectively.